# Issues in the class path of dependency jar file in update site of a eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde

I have created  a eclipse plugin by using maven tycho, which has a dependency plugin called  com.test.antlr .which I already created and exported as  a plugin. During my maven build for the update site the com.test.antlr class path entry is changed.The main plugin called com.test.main and the dependency com.test.antlr is added to the feature project.And it is refernced it to the update site which has a packing of eclipse-repository. During the build it generated a zip file with the plugin and features.The plugin folder contains com.test.antlr and the main plugin. But the class path entry is changed from java 1.6 to the following

```
<classpathentry kind="con"  path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
```

and in the meta.mf file of the dependency plugin(com.test.antlr ) is changed from

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

to

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

My eclipse class path only have java 1.6 i dint install java 1.7 . The class path is automatically converted. please help me am very much in need of this.

Comment: "During my maven build for the update site the com.test.antlr class path entry is changed" - Tycho never writes the Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment header, so I have my doubts that your problem description is complete.

Comment: Looking at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709075/the-plugin-is-doesnt-work-when-i-exported-or-maven-install-it), it becomes pretty clear that you have edited some derived file. On re-build this file is overwritten, so it may appear as if it was "changed" by the build.